# daterangepicker is over all items

Tags: html, css, daterangepicker

Please note I am using daterangepicker : (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker)
I had a problem that input all time is over all items (like boostrap Modal or menu )

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
<div class="picker-carte" style="position:relative;">
<label for="datePicker" class=" control-label">Select date :</label>
 <input type="text" name="datePicker" class="form-control daterangepicker" value="{{$start_date}} - {{$end_date}}" data-start="{{$start_date}}" data-end="{{$end_date}}">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried :

```
style="position:relative;"
```

or the add to class picker-carte:

```
.picker-carte {
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

the page look :
[image]

an

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is seems they give to class daterangepicker a x-index = 3001

I used the below css and it fixed .

```
.daterangepicker { 
z-index: 0!important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing the datepicker, increase the "top bar"'s `z-index`

```css
.top-bar { /* or whatever class or ID has your top bar */
  position: relative; /* or whatever */
  z-index: 100; /* or as needed */
}
```